# Xcode 7.1 : 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, xcode7

I am building an app with Parse as the backend and with Xcode 7.1. I am **NOT** using cocoa pods. My app was building on the device just fine, however when I try to run it on the simulator I get

> 'Parse/Parse.h' file not found

I have included Parse.framework in my project folder and my framework search path is

> $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)

Why is this error occurring only for the simulator and how do I go about solving it?

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

My project is now running on the simulator. I changed my framework search path to

> $(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/projectname

Then in my build phases I actually had a duplicate MessageUI.framework.

So I deleted both, re-added one, and then made sure there was no duplicates in my 'Frameworks' project folder.

After removing duplicates my project ran!

Comment: Can you remove the solution out of your question and submit it as a proper answer? (Slightly related to Meta question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301)

Answer (score 0):

What about trying out Cocoapods?

Simple as `pod "Parse"` and everything should be working.

If you have an aversion to Cocoapods for some reason check to make sure that the frameworks are weakly linked.

[Another SO question that may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794422/xcode-library-not-found-lpods-bolts-exit-code-1)

Comment: I get "linker command failed with exit code 1....framework not found Parse"" after I run pod install

Comment: Did you check the weak linking? If that doesn't work I'd try running a 'pod deintegrate' and then 'pod install' again. You can google pod deintegrate to figure out how to install. Your Cocoapods install might have been messed up. Other than that, not much more I can do.

Comment: [also check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794422/xcode-library-not-found-lpods-bolts-exit-code-1)

Comment: I get !] Unknown command: `Parse`
Did you mean: cache?  is this thing actually worked lots of questions on SO too and not a clear answer, we all deleted , added, fix the search path still that bloody Parse/PArse.h not found