# library not found for -lPods-Bolts

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode6

> ld: library not found for -lPods-Bolts
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Getting this error when I try to compile my code, been stuck on it for so long, think its pretty simple to anyone who knows Xcode development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might help:

- [xCode: Library not found - lPods-Bolts - Exit Code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794422/xcode-library-not-found-lpods-bolts-exit-code-1?rq=1)
- [library not found for -lPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863836/library-not-found-for-lpods?rq=1)

Other than that, off the top of my head, here are a couple of things you can try:

1. Make sure you have cocoapods installed locally on your machine, and that your environment has a path to it.  From a shell prompt, do the following:

   $ pod --version

   You should see something like "0.39.0" or "1.0.0".  If you see "No such file or directory", you'll need to [install it](https://cocoapods.org/) (make sure to read the "Install" **and** "Getting Started" sections completely)
2. Make sure you have all of your project's pod dependencies installed:

   $ pod install
3. Do a clean build

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I did what you said and it worked when I opened the .xcworkspace file in the project :)

Thanks again